# Fix a constant width for first sidebar and second sidebar

Tags: theming, blocks

I'm working on `Zero point Theme` in drupal 7. In my home page I've three blocks - `first sidebar`, `content` and `second sidebar` formatted as three columns. Here the width of first sidebar and second sidebar are equal and the content has its own width (I'm ok with that). There are some pages where I have only first sidebar and content.

Previously, I was facing a problem like if I go to other pages(other than home-page) the first sidebar's width will be increased. I don't like the view so I changed the `CSS`.

I gave a fixed width to the blocks by editing the CSS -

```
.block.themed-block{
                    width: 60%; 
                   }
```

Now, the first sidebar and second sidebar has `constant width` in all pages.

My Issue is : when I go to other pages where I have only first sidebar and content page, the width of the first sidebar is reduced and the content part doesn't appear from where the first sidebar ends, it leaves some space between the first sidebar and the content part. It shows some odd effect. I want the content part to start from where the first sidebar ends. Is there any way to get rid of that.

Below, I share the screenshot of my Issue.

[image]

Highlighted rectangle part is the space, that I want to get rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, before your css editing, the index block filled that white space, right?

you changed the width of the sidebar's content, rather than the sidebar itself (which is a region, not a block)

i don't know of the zero point theme, but look for an outer class, like .sidebar, or .sidebar-first, and set the with of that.

---

i looked into that particular theme.

revert all the css editing and go to the theme settings, under "layout setting -> sidebars layout" try using the 'fixed' options instead than the 'variable'.

Comment: I was trying to find .sidebar or .sidebar-first in my theme folder. But I couldn't any of such kind.

Comment: yes, got you.. found the class names through firebug lite. Just changed those in CSS.

Comment: Hey no, it works fine on pages that contains sidebar and content. If there is only content, the content part moves out of the page border.

Comment: Is There any other way to move the content towards left.

Comment: After Edit : that was awesome, it works. I should really thank you.